# How to copy multiple files to multiple targets in SkyDrive

Tags: windows, onedrive, copy-paste

I want to copy a couple of files that I have to each of about 12 different folders, so that each of the folders has a different copy of the file in it.

Currently, I am using the 'Copy to' option in the context menu, manually copying each file to each folder, but there has to be a better way to do this.

Things I would like to be able to do include

- Copy more than one file to a destination at a time
- Copy a file to more than one destination at a time
- Copy more than one file to more than one destination at a time

How can I do that more efficiently?

I am using Windows XP, with Chrome and Internet Explorer installed (I can install some other browser if one of them can be used for my task).

I am not scared of using command line scripting (in any flavor), but I do not know how to or even if I can get a shell in the SkyDrive environment. 
I am considering writing a bot program to do this, but I thought I'd ask to see if anyone knows a better way.

Comment: This is not a question about a Web Application